# PHP How to take specific VAR from one php and place it in another severals php files into $sql value

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, include

I recently started with MySQL and it's my first time coding in php. So I hope you can help me:

I have a few php files like insert.php, update.php, delete.php etc. and in each of them is the same name of Table, for example:

**delete.php**

`<?php $sql = "DELETE FROM name_of_table WHERE .... ?>`

**insert.php**

`<?php $sql = "INSERT INTO name_of_table ... ?>`

**update.php**

`<?php $sql = "UPDATE name_of_table SET ... ?>`

etc.

I want to create one php file, where will be all these sqls and insert each sql (sql1, sql2, sql3) to specific php file (like this upload, delete, insert.php, etc) into $sql value.

*Example:*

**all_sqls.php**

```
<?php $sql1 = "name_of_table" ?>

<?php $sql2 = "name_of_table" ?>

<?php $sql3 = "name_of_table" ?>
```

And now connect each sql from all_sqls.php to specific php file and into value of $sql :

**delete.php**

`<?php $sql = "DELETE FROM .include("all_sqls.php", "$sql1") WHERE ...?>`

**insert.php**

`<?php $sql = "INSERT INTO .include("all_sqls.php", "$sql2") ... ?>`

**update.php**

`<?php $sql = "UPDATE .include("all_sqls.php", "$sql3") SET... ?>`

After that I will just change name_of_table in all_sqls.php all at once.

I know this code is wrong, I want edit all name_of_table in one php file and don't open each separate and rename it (it's waste of time).

Let's automate this together if it's possible!

Uncle Google has not helped me :(

Comment: Why do you want to change the table name? A table name is not something that changes so often that it's even require an automation.

Comment: You mention `include`, did you take a look at [how to use it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)?

Comment: Automation is a good thing, but given  you only *started* with PHP and mysql, you need to write everything as is, just to get a feel of the code. Only after a while consider some automation.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have some sort of config file that holds all tables, you can simply outsource it to another php file and `require()` it, what basically is an `include()` that aborts the script when the target is not present.

```php
// tables.php
<?php
$SQLtables = [
    'name_of_table_1',
    'name_of_table_2',
    'name_of_table_3'
];
?>
```

Prepend `require('tables.php');` at the beginning of each of your query php files. This will make *$SQLtables* available for that file.

You can then either access each member of *$SQLtables* using `$SQLtables[line]`. Replace *line* by the line number in your definition, first line is numbered 0. So: `$SQLtables[0]` would resolve in *'name_of_table1'* in this example.

> After that I will just change name_of_table in all_sqls.php all at once.

If you want to go through all the list, you can use foreach.

```
foreach ($SQLtables as $table_name) {
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE ...';
    // Execute SQL query
}
```

Comment: This $SQLtables makes absolutely no sense. As well as a loop that deletes from several tables by their names.

Comment: "After that I will just change name_of_table in all_sqls.php all at once.", did I get this wrong? I'm not sure what QA is up to, but I think my code does pretty much what he asked for

Comment: Definitely QA is not a quiz where you test your skill of guesswork. Many questions do not qualify for a QA site and must be closed. If you like challenges, consider participating at code golf or Advent of Code events instead

Comment: I might still need to get used to things here. I see a question and try to assist if I can, unless it is closed. It's not up to me to decide if a question is worthy. I'm just trying to help Yanin on the way. And I see nothing wrong with my answer.

Comment: That's true. Sometimes it takes another pair of eyes

Comment: And I'd love to see one. Maybe by the one who asked the question. Merry christmas, Your Common Sense :-)